# Android Getting JSON return error from POST Http execution

Tags: android, json, http, exception, post

I'm currently trying to send data via POST to a server, and the server is handling the data and appends it to a JSON file. I'm currently getting a 422 error and I've been receiving it for a while now. My question is: How do I receive that JSON error itself in Java so that I can see what the error is. All I'm seeing is a HttpResponseException and it doesn't give me anything else. Thanks for the time and help in advance.

```
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mPath);
        // Add your data
    try
    {
        List nameValuePairs = new ArrayList(4);
        httppost.setHeader("Authorization", Base64.encodeToString(new StringBuilder(bundleId).append(":").append(apiKey).toString().getBytes("UTF-8"), Base64.URL_SAFE|Base64.NO_WRAP));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("state", "CA"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("city", "AndDev is Cool!"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("body", "dsads is assrawstjljalsdfljasldflkasjdfjasldjflasjdflkjaslfggddsfgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfdsgfddjflaskjdfkasjdlfkjasldfkjalskdjfajasldfkasdlfjasljdflajsdfjasdjflaskjdflaksjdfljasldfkjasljdflajsasdlfkjasldfkjlas!"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", "dsaghhhe fd!"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        //HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        //int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
        Log.v(TAG, "response: " + responseBody);
        //JSONObject response = new JSONObject(responseBody); 
        int f = 0;
    }
    catch(HttpResponseException e)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using something like [hurl.it](http://hurl.it/) to check the message you get on the server? `curl` suffices too.

Comment: Oh wow. That really helps debug it! Bookmarked! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may send your parameters more conveniently by using predefined Json class as below:

```
    String jsonParam = null;
    try{
        JSONObject param = new JSONObject();
        param.put("state", "CA");
        param.put("city", "AndDev is Cool!");
        //and so on with other parameters

        jsonParam = param.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
```

and set the post entity as:

```
if(jsonParam != null)
     httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonParam, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

Answer (score 1):

422 error says: `Unprocessable Entity - The request was well-formed but was unable to be followed due to semantic errors`

You got a problem with `UrlEncodedFormEntity`

Comment: Yeah, I'm assuming it's an issue with my structure now that I reevaluate it. Thanks.